# Custom type for jsonschema

Tags: validation, jsonschema

I also validate my objects with [JSON Schema](https://json-schema.org/). There is a case when I need to validate a date field. I use tutorials from here. But I cannot find how to define a custom type. There is a workaround that consists to create a custom property. This is oblivious that a way should exist. But I do not see.
Thank you.

Comment: Can you give more info on what you need to validate on the date field ?

Answer (score 1):

You already have a built-in date format in [JSON schema](https://json-schema.org/understanding-json-schema/reference/string.html#built-in-formats), so you should use it instead of custom type.

Comment: Your link follows on a page with the JSON schema documentation that describes date formats for the type `string`. It validates strings and suspects date formated.

Comment: I see that I should use the type `object` and add custom property implementaion `instanceOf`

Comment: If you just need to validate a date, you don't need a custom object type. You just use the standard built-in date format in the JSON schema. Then make sure that dates are serialized in output JSON as strings formatted according to the JSON schema built-in date format, and use any JSON schema implementation (supporting draft 7 or later) to validate your date field.

Comment: It does not work. It does not convert types automatically. It throws an error that it suspects a string object the date object is met,

Comment: Well, in your post, you were asking for type validation. If you want type conversion, this is a bigger issue and more info is needed. The solution depends on your programming language or JSON library that you are using for data mapping. So you need to give more info on your actual software environment.